# .htaccess redirect, css/images no longer loading

Tags: .htaccess

I have a simple HTML project sat on a hosting account in a folder called 'buddies', its full url looks something like this http://www.example.com/buddies/

I'm trying to re-write URL's to point to PHP files like this;

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ((?:css|images|js)/.*)$ /$1 [L]

# About Us
RewriteRule ^about_us/what_we_do/?$ about-what-we-do.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^about_us/mission/?$ about-our-mission.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^about_us/team/?$ about-team.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^about_us/what_next/?$ about-what-next.php [NC,L]

# Classes
RewriteRule ^classes/learn/?$ classes-learn.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^classes/1to1/?$ classes-one-to-one.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^classes/swim_fit/?$ class-swim-fit.php [NC,L]

# Information
RewriteRule ^information/timetable/?$ info-timetable.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^information/contact/?$ info-contact.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^information/location/?$ info-locations.php [NC,L]
```

This works great at redirecting to the URL to the correct PHP file, however in doing this it's broke the links to all images and css files. I understand why it's doing it, the css and images folders don't exist in the path 'about_us/what_we_do/'

If this was running in the root of the domain, I'd simply prepend a '/' to the front of all images/css files i.e. '/css/style.css' rather than how they're currently referenced 'css/style.css'.

Can someone suggest a way in which I can still server css, images and javascript from the folders 'css', 'images' and 'js'? Without me having to prepend the 'buddies' folder to each and every css/image reference.

EDIT: I'm referencing the stylesheet like this;

```
<!-- Stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style-768.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style-992.css">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all CSS files are in the directory `/css`, you can just rewrite each to this directory

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (css/.*\.css)$ /$1 [L]
```

The `RewriteCond` is there to avoid a rewrite loop, if requests are for `/css/...`.

Similar for images and Javascript files. You may even combine all into one rule, if you just look at the directories

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ((?:css|images|js)/.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

This looks for any request starting with either `css/`, `images/` or `js/`.

---

If the CSS files are not in `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/css`, but `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/buddies/css`, the target must be prefixed accordingly, e.g.

```
RewriteRule ((?:css|images|js)/.*)$ /buddies/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I prefer the second approach but sadly even with that it still doesn't work. I've updated the code in my original question.

Comment: Where are the CSS files located? Is it `/css/style.css` or maybe `/buddies/css/style.css`?

Comment: they're located at /buddies/css/style.css

Answer (score 1):

Use `<base href="http://www.example.com/">`so it will redirect your external files to that directory.

Comment: This solution does work, however I'd like to avoid adding code to every page, and rather have it managed in a single file (.htaccess) if I can to ease maintenance.